# Copy from command in oracle using common table expression

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to copy data from one table into another in the same database but different schema using a query that uses `cte`:

```
COPY FROM my_schema/password -
INSERT PRODUCT -
USING 
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
    p.id,
    p.vendor,
    p.name,
    p.product_alias,
    p.platform
    FROM
        memuat.product p
        JOIN memuat.licence_management l 
        ON p.id = l.product_id
), 
joined as (
SELECT
    cte.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vendor,name ORDER BY vendor,name ) as rn
    from cte 
) 
select ID,VENDOR,NAME,PLATFORM,PRODUCT_ALIAS from joined where rn =1;
```

The query runs successfully but the sql statement is empty:

```
SQL statement to execute cannot be empty or null
>>Query Run In:Query Result 7
```

I think this is because the `cte` creates a temporary table that doesn't exist in the database, so the copy command can't copy anything. Is there a way to copy using `ctes` ??

Comment: I think you need to add a '-' at the end of each line.

Comment: what does a '-' do there ? I copied that from oracle documentation but not sure what that means

Comment: line completion for the copy command

Answer (score 2):

Using the inline hint will not create a global temporary table but process the cte as an query INLINE ,hence try the below

```
            COPY FROM my_schema/password -
            INSERT PRODUCT -
            USING 
            WITH cte AS (
                SELECT /*+ inline */
                p.id,
                p.vendor,
                p.name,
                p.product_alias,
                p.platform
                FROM
                    memuat.product p
                    JOIN memuat.licence_management l 
                    ON p.id = l.product_id
            ), 
            joined as (
            SELECT /*+ inline */
                cte.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vendor,name ORDER BY vendor,name ) as rn
                from cte 
            ) 
            select ID,VENDOR,NAME,PLATFORM,PRODUCT_ALIAS from joined where rn =1;
```

Comment: that did not work for me.

Comment: try copy without cte by creating views for cte and joined